# is there a way to change nav bar header text value office 365 add-in which is opened in mobile

Tags: office365-apps, office-js, outlook-web-addins

is there a way to change nav bar header text which is set to default 'Outlook Add-in' when users open office 365 add-in in mobile device ?
apps showing as following image in small devices

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI you provide in the post is belong the OWA instead of Mail add-in. At present, it is not able to customize the header text in the figure above. Here is the [manifest](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/manifests) which used to control the mail add-in.

You can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you need this feature in the Mail add-in.